# File already opened in another unit Program aborted.

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

Here is the program I wrote to test multiple-thread reading a file independently:

```
program he
    use omp_lib

    implicit none
    integer :: i, a(20), funit

    open(unit=2, file='dat/he', status='replace')
    write(2, '(i2/, i2/, i2/, i2)') 1, 3, 5, 7
    close(2)

    !$omp parallel do num_threads(20) private(funit)
    do i = 1, 20
        funit=100+omp_get_thread_num()
        open(funit, file='dat/he', status='old')
        read(funit,'(i2)') a(i)
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do

    print *, a
end program he
```

I compiled it by gfortran compiler without getting any errors: `gfortran -fopenmp -o exe a.f90`, and run `./exe`, but got different errors each time I ran `./exe`. However, I also compiled it using ifort: `ifort -qopenmp -o exe a.f90`, and ran it, `./exe`, successfully.

One of the errors from gfortran in runtime is

```
At line 15 of file fortran_learning_book.f90 (unit = 102)
Fortran runtime error: File already opened in another unit

Program aborted. Backtrace:

Program aborted. Backtrace:
#0  0x10c30aff2
#0  0x10c30aff2

Program aborted.
```

Comment: You have a problem in your code, ask how to fix it. Don't ask which compiler is better, that is **completely offtopic**.  Just fix your buggy code, don't blame the compiler.

Comment: BTW, I still don't know why you you want this. I read your last question, but I still don't know. I can only assure you that placing the `open` statement for a single file in a parallel loop like this is a bad idea.

Comment: This approach is madness turned into code !  Forgive my bluntness (or not, take offence if you wish to) but it looks as if OP doesn't yet have enough experience of OpenMP to know how wrong this approach is.  OpenMP is about shared memory computing.  Have one thread read the values of `a` into memory, make it a shared object, and let individual threads do as they wish with the elements.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not a valid standard Fortran and therefore exhibits undefined behaviour with different compilers. The Fortran standard is pretty clear that:

> If a file is already connected to a unit, an OPEN statement on that file with a different unit shall not be executed.

(Section 9.5.6.1 from ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010)

Unlike some other languages, standard Fortran does not allow the same file to be opened multiple times.

**Edit:** As IanH noted, the upcoming Fortran standard (informally known as Fortran 2015) will formally remove the restriction but will still leave to the implementation the decision of whether multiple connections to the same file are allowed or not.

Both GNU Fortran and Intel Fortran are capable of compiling **correct** Fortran code with OpenMP extensions.

Comment: This changes with F2015 - "It is processor dependent whether a file can be connected to more than one unit at the same time."  (12.5.4p4).

Comment: But ifort seems to not complain about this. Is there such a restriction in ifort?

Comment: Most compilers deviate from the standards in one way or another. I'm not sure if there has even been a Fortran compiler that follows the standard from the first to the last letter.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the origin of your problem is that you didn't give any `action` parameter to your `open` statement. Indeed, the default action to allow (either `read`, `write` or `readwrite`) on a newly opened file is implementation defined. Therefore, you are potentially opening several times in parallel the same file in for example `readwrite` mode, allowing in particular the `write` mode from several independent units, leading to potential file inconsistencies. Then the compiler and/or run time library may or may not check for this sort of (in)consistency and report it as an error... From what it looks like, gfrotran and ifort have a different approach in at least one of the two parts (default action and/or RTL check).

The only case were this sort of parallel opening of the same file is "legitimate" and secure is if you restrict your access to reading mode. Therefore, adding the `action='read'` to your `open` statement might just fix the issue. Indeed, it does it for me with gfortran version 5.4.0.

Now, we are in a grey area here (at least for me) and I truly don't know how portable / standard compliant this all is. Therefore, although I believe this solves your immediate issue, I couldn't comment on the overall portability of the code between different compilers.

Comment: A file may not be connected to more than one unit at a given time, regardless of what actions are specified.  What a compiler does when one breaks that rule is its choice.

Comment: 9.5.6.1 from the Fortran 2008 specification: _"8. If a file is already connected to a unit, an OPEN statement on that file with a different unit shall not be executed."_

Comment: @Gilles My gfortran version is 5.3.0, and adding `action='read'` does not solve the problem. I tried to install version 5.4.0 by macport `sudo port install gcc5 @5.4.0`, but got an error :

Comment: @Gilles --->  Computing dependencies for gcc5
--->  Cleaning gcc5
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
Warning: Error parsing file /Applications/MacPorts/Python 2.7/Python Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Python Launcher: Error opening or reading file
Warning: Error parsing file /Applications/MacPorts/AquaTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/AquaTerm: Error opening or reading file
--->  No broken files found.

Comment: @Gilles How did you install version 5.4.0?\